# I am trying to compare values in two columns from two different tables

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have two tables, tableA and tableB. TableA has 4 columns while tableB has 3 columns. the last column of tableA is blank and in this column I want to display the difference between my third columns in tableA and B.

tableA name = valuation_average.
tableB name = valuation_cost.
both of their third column names is cost_col (but the values are different and I want to display this difference in the 4th column in tableA called Difference, this column is already there and named it is just void of values.)

Also keep in mind that the rows may not equal, what I mean by this is that the first row in tableA may not be the same as the first row in tableB. the primary key is the first column of both tables called "code"

Answer (score 0):

You can try [mysql-update-join](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/).

And in you case,maybe

```
UPDATE valuation_average a,valuation_cost c SET a.difference = a.cost_col - c.cost_col WHERE a.code = c.code
```

can solve your problem.